# Onboarding User Without External Library Angular 14

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am building an onboarding for a web app built in Angular that follows this basic premise. A new user, once authenticated, will land on a page that is built from 2 components (a home component which contains the navbar and footer, and the search component which contains a search bar and filter button). The relationship between the two components is that the search component is presented through a router-outlet in the home component.

I would like the new user to be forced to make a search (with a filter), and then after they see the search results, press an additional button to complete the onboarding. However, while they do this I would not like them to be able to click on the links in. the navbar or go complete other actions on the site.

An initial idea would be just to figure out how to disable all the other buttons/available actions in the home component and search component while this onboarding is walked through by the user and toggle buttons back on as steps are completed, but it seems like that is not the best way to build this out. Given that the majority of the onboarding is contained in a single component, what are best practices to build this out? Is there a way to manage the state of all the buttons / actions in the component in some kind of array and move through the array?

EDIT: I think the biggest point of confusion I have is what I should be using to manage the component as the user steps through the onboarding. Like will I just need a bunch of booleans or flags that are enabled when I know the user is new and just disable all of those logic elements when the user is not new?

Comment: Personally I think that creating a service which holds a state with some ngIf on your template could work.

Comment: may just skip the part with disabling buttons. If the user is not onboarded disable the overflow and put a div with absolute positioning 100 vh height and 100 vw width and high z-index with the additional button inside infront of everything. everything behind it would be still visible but would not be clickable. Not the pretiest solution but would be the easiest. little bit similar to these anti adblock banners

Comment: @RicardoMachado Could you explain a bit more about "holding state with some ngIf"? Does that mean like creating some array of state values for buttons and items and stepping through that array as a user moves through the onboarding? Or like using a service with subjects to manage as the user moves through the flow?

Comment: @Mucksh So add a layer and move buttons above or below that layer depending on the step of the onboarding? I think what I am missing is what I should be using to manage the state of the component as the user moves through the onboarding

Comment: @rye_bread to manage the state just place logic of the onboarding process in a service that handles it, If the components know the service you can handle all the state stuff in it. If there a multiple steps in the onboarding may use an enum that holds the current state of it untlil the submit.

Comment: @Mucksh What does managing state entail? Does that mean managing whether buttons are active or disabled, if elements are hidden or shown through simple mechanism like ngShow, hidden, etc? Or is there a different way to manage state through the service?

Comment: @rye_bread there are many ways to accomplish what you want. How you do it is your choice. I would say an easy way would be just place a bool in the service that hold if the user is already onboarded or logged in. May take the information e.g. from a different service that knows if the user is logged in. If you reference the service in your main compontent you can change the ui according to that. If there is not more complex stuff to it just keep it simple and don't build an overengineered mess

Comment: I would reference it in your main home component and if it is false and the search is completed just show the onboarding compontent in the forground and the div behind it infront of the other stuff. May add some dark color with opacity to it to show the rest is diabled. I think to disable each button would be a little bit impractical. Not sure do what you want. May I also miss a some feature that would do the same without cluttering everything